# How to check for empty object id in populate method?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to populate array of objects using the following code:

```
inventory.populate(result, {
    path: 'activities.mean', 
    $match: { 'activities.mean': {$ne: ''} } 
 }, callback);
```

where type of `mean` is:

```
mean:{type:String, ref: 'Inventory'}
```

While populating a result I get the error in my callback function:

> CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id" for model "Inventory"'...

Which clearly shows that I've results that contains empty `activities.mean`.

I tried different solutions provided including `match` that I wrote in above code but I can't really make it work. Not sure why `match` is not working here.

**What I'm expecting this code to do is:**

if `activities.mean` is empty string, then do not try to populate that `mean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More looks like that the issue is that you're using `String` type for a reference field – because of that mongoose is trying to cast string values to ObjectId which is normally used for references. It should be

```
mean: {
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Inventory'
}
```

Mongoose's [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) itself notes that

> Note: ObjectId, Number, String, and Buffer are valid for use as refs. However, you should use ObjectId unless you are an advanced user and have a good reason for doing so.